# When creating a custom Blog CMS, what should one implement to be able to use it with LiveWriter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blogs, windows-live-writer

I am currently building my own small scale Blog CMS with ASP MVC C#.

I was just curious if anybody out there made such a thing **connect with LiveWriter**,and could point me in this direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched the web and found the code and have to answer my own question lol:

http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-RPC-ping-endpoint-in-C-and-ASPNET.aspx